# Unable to Install Wordpress on Google App Engine

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I followed this tutorial to set up Wordpress on Google App Engine:
http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

I run the application in the GAE Launcher, then go to this address:

```
http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/install.php
```

This should run the Wordpress installer.  However, it simply displays "Hello world!"

Here is the Launcher log:

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
--skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8000
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2014-09-23 22:06:18,670 devappserver2.py:725] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-09-23 22:06:18,673 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-09-23 22:06:18,676 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:52328
INFO     2014-09-23 22:06:18,680 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-09-23 22:06:18,684 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2014-09-23 22:06:38,979 module.py:652] default: "GET /wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 200 12
```

Comment: Could you post the content of your app.yaml file?

Comment: This seems not to be based with your yaml file, as it would, in any case, affect your deployment to GAE not the localhost, as the rest is provided by default. The first time you run it properly from localhost:8080, it will redirect you to the admin page without further ado (you're not going that way). Check that you really can access your local MySQL with your root password, that the password is properly set in wp-config.php, that that file is in the innermost wordpress directory, that you have installed php-cgi along with php-mysql, and you're passing the correct path to php-cgi executables.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like instead of finding the correct project in the starter project folder, it created a new project (the "Hello world!" you see is the default when you create a new project with no content), possibly in a subdirectory of your starter project folder. Try removing your project from the app engine launcher, and then dragging the folder with the project files into the app engine launcher project list pane (which should cause it to be created as a project).